# RoR routing problem. Calling custom action, but getting redirected to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I am working on a project in ruby on rails and I am having a very difficult time with a basic problem. I am trying to call a custom action in one of my controllers, but the request is somehow getting redirected to the default 'show' action and I cannot figure out why.

link in edit.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Mass Text Entry', :action=>"create_or_add_food_item_from_text" %>
```

Error from development.log:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Menu with ID=create_or_add_food_item_from_text): app/controllers/menus_controller.rb:20:in `show'
```

routes.rb file:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
map.resources :nutrition_objects
map.resources :preference_objects
map.resources :institutions
map.resources :locations
map.resources :menus
map.resources :food_items
map.resources :napkins
map.resources :users
map.resource  :session, :controller => 'session'

map.root :controller=>'pages', :action=>'index'

map.about  '/about',  :controller=>'pages', :action=>'about'
map.contact '/contact', :controller=>'pages', :action=>'contact'
map.home   '/home',    :controller=>'pages', :action=>'index'

map.user_home   '/user/home',   :controller=>'rater', :action=>'index'
map.user_napkins   '/user/napkins', :controller=>'rater', :action=>'view_napkins'
map.user_preferences  '/user/preferences',:controller=>'rater', :action=>'preferences'

map.blog   '/blog', :controller=>'pages', :action=>'blog'
map.signup  '/signup',  :controller=>'users',  :action=>'new'
map.login  '/login',  :controller=>'session', :action=>'new'
map.logout  '/logout',  :controller=>'session', :action=>'destroy'

# Install the default routes as the lowest priority. 
map.connect ':controller/:action'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id' 
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Menus_controller.rb:

```
class MenusController < ApplicationController
...
   def create_or_add_food_item_from_text  
   end
...
end
```

create_or_add_food_item_from_text.html.erb simply has a div to show a form with a text box in it. I have the rest of my app working fine, but this is stumping me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the route to your file explicitly, **before** the `:menus` resources:

```
map.connect "/menus/create_or_add_food_item_from_text",
  :controller => "menus", :action => "create_or_add_food_item_from_text"

map.resources ...
```

Routes declared earlier have higher priority, and the problem here is that `map.resources` actually prevents certain paths from being routed.

Even regardless of this issue, it's good practice to map all paths explicitly, either through resources or named/unnamed routes, and ultimately eliminate the generic `:controller/:action` and `:controller/:action/:id` routes from your app.

Comment: I rearranged my routes.rb file and declared the route explicitly before the :menus resources like you suggested. It worked out fine. Thanks for the quick suggestion

Answer (score 0):

link_to expects the path to your action as the second parameter - it looks like you are passing link_to the wrong path value. Check the development log to see what path rails thinks you are looking for.

Comment: The rails documentation has link_to(name, options = {}, html_options = nil), so I am pretty sure that I set up the link correctly